# URL routing functionality to Angular Material Tabs

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm using angular material tabs to display information in each tab, I want to be able to copy/paste URL to share each tab state to different users.

I managed to change URL depending on which tab I have clicked, but when I paste that URL it doesn't work.

So far code looks like this:

```
<mat-tab-group (selectedTabChange)="changeRoute($event)">
    <mat-tab *ngFor="let object of Projects">
        <!-- info here -->
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

Function:

```
changeRoute(project: any) {
    const queryParams: Params = { projName: project.tab.textLabel };

    this.router.navigate(
      [],
      {
        relativeTo: this.activatedRoute,
        queryParams: queryParams,
        queryParamsHandling: 'merge',
      });
}
```

Comment: Can you make example on stackblitz?

Comment: You need to make active tab from queryParams? Or how do you get routing?